# What applications do i need to download to start developing apps using spring framework?

Tags: java, spring

I need to start developing applications using spring framework, and am wondering what tools do i need to download to have me up and running.

On the [springsource](http://www.springsource.com/download/community?project=)website am seeing all this applications to download and am wondering do i really need all this? And what versions should i use, especially for Spring Framework?

```
* Spring Framework 
* SpringSource dm Server Samples
* Spring Security 
* Spring Web Flow 
* Spring Web Services 
* Spring Dynamic Modules
* Spring Integration
* Spring Batch
* Spring.NET
* Spring JavaConfig
* Spring LDAP
* Spring Extensions
* Spring IDE
* Spring BlazeDS Integration
* SpringSource Bundlor
* Spring ROO
```

What other applications do i need to download (eg. strut, glassfish, apache etc)

Gath

Comment: you asked this question twice:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824917/what-applications-do-i-need-to-download-to-start-developing-apps-using-spring-fra

Answer (score 1):

You only need two things:

- Spring framework (with minimal dependencies); and
- A servlet container (eg Tomcat) or a full-blown application server (eg Glassfish, JBoss).

Everything else is optional.

I believe the only required dependency is Apache Commons logging. Depending on what features you use, you may well need more.

You don't say what you actually want to do with Spring but I'm assuming - since this is most often the case - it's build Web applications. If so, here is a [tutorial](http://maestric.com/en/doc/java/spring) that creates a barebones Spring MVC project. There are countless others around for that and other topics.

Comment: You can also use the Spring framework without a servlet container, in a 'standalone' java application.

Comment: @cletus: The duplicate question has more answers. Could you repost this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824917/ ?