# Multi threaded FastCGI java libraries

Tags: java, multithreading, fastcgi

Where i can get multi threaded FastCGI libraries for Java?
And how I should configure nginx, that it supported the processing of multiple concurrent requests.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a very special use-case, you shouldn't need multi-threaded FastCGI libraries. You can use `fcgistarter` (with the `-N` flag) and the Apache `mod_proxy` load balancers to distribute load over multiple FastCGI servers.

Here's an answer I made that explains how to build FastCGI apps with Java/Apache: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15033764/309483

Answer (score -3):

You don't use FastCGI with java; Java systems usually have their own web server and you just proxy requests to them from the primary (front-end) web server.

Comment: Possible question. No answer.